# PopUp Activity starts again when it is started from "recent apps"

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have a PopUp activity that starts when the AlarmManager receives an alarm.

AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
    service.putExtras(intent);

    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, service);
}
```

AlarmService extends IntentService:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(this, PopUpActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    AlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

PopUpActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_dialog);



    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, ClientConstants.WAKE_LOCK_NOTIFICATION);
    // Acquire the lock
    wl.acquire();

    if (canVibrate){
        vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(new long[]{ 0, 200, 500 },0);
    }
    if (canRing){
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, getAlarmUri());
            final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) {
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok_button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopRinging();
            finish();
        }
    });
    // Release the lock
    wl.release();
}
private void stopRinging(){
    if (canRing && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    if (canVibrate){
        vibrator.cancel();
    }
}
```

PopUpActivity is started from an alarm manager. If PopUpActivity is started when the application is not the active application, and if user presses "OK button", activity disappears. Nothing is wrong right here till now. **The problem is, if user opens recent apps screen and selects the activity a new PopUpActivity is started again**. How can i get rid off this problem?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail.what was your requirement when the user select from recent app screen.

Answer (score 4):

When you declare your PopupActivity in your manifest, make sure you include `android:noHistory="true"`. This will mean that as soon as you open "recents", the popup activity will be forgotten, and you will just return to where you were before when you re-open the app.

Answer (score 3):

When user presses `Ok` button, `Activity.finish()` method is being called. This results in the `Activity` being destroyed. Hence when user selects the app from recent app section, the `Activity` is created again.

In case you don't want to destroy the `Activity` but want to put it in background, replace Activity.finish() method with [Activity.moveTaskToBack(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack%28boolean%29).

```
findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok_button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        stopRinging();
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
});
```

You need to handle scenarios wherein `Activity` is restarted after being killed due to memory shortage and configuration changes.

You can set [FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) in the `Activity` launch `Intent` flags, to ensure the new instance is not created if it is already running at the top of the history stack.

Comment: Sorry i could not award your bounty then,  i upvoted now

Comment: No issues. Happy to know that the answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, under the section for your `Activity`, try this:

```
<activity>            
     android:launchMode="singleTask"
</activity>
```

In case you want your `Activity` **not to show up in your recent apps list**, try

```
<activity>            
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
</activity>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want my app to show up in recent apps list.
launchMode="singleTask" didnt work

Answer (score 0):

When you press OK button, you `finish()` the activity and selecting it again from history will obviously re-create it.

What you should do is hide this alarm activity from history/recents using `android:excludeFromRecents="true"`

and use `launchMode = "singleInstance"` with this so that android can never make another two instances of this activity at same time.

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid from this problem simply by adding flag to the intent that starts the activity indicating not to be shown in the recent tasks:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(this, PopUpActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
startActivity(i);
```

setting the [`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS) will make your PopupActivity invisible on the recent tasks.